# "SEE" files in web directory

Tags: website

I would like to know/list filenames in a web directory.
Files are downloadable from a link but directory listing is forbidden for some reason
for e.g http://www.abcxyz.com/XYZ/SM_ABC.zip can download file `SM_ABC.zip`
but http://www.abcxyz.com/XYZ/ gives forbidden message.

So I was thinking if I have all filenames then I would just edit individual url to download that file as it is downloadable.

Any simple to use ideas?

Comment: If it's forbidden, then directory listing has been disabled. You can't see the listing, therefore you can't get a list of files to edit the URL and download.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? I see what looks like you've figured out a solution, followed by a vague call for ideas (for what?).

Comment: @BowlesCR Well I believe they wanted to get a list of the filenames without having access to the directory listing, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: This question really needs to narrow down the options for our answers. There are literally thousands of ways to do this. Nearly every webserver has a way, nearly every server side scripting language has a way, nearly every OS has ways.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using PHP:

```
<?php
$prepend="http://example.com/path/to/resources/";
$files=glob("*.txt");
if(count($files)>0) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($files as $file)
      echo "\t<li><a href=$prepend$file>$file</a>\n";
    echo "</ul>\n";
} else echo "<p>There are no items to display.</p>\n";
?>
```

Name this `index.php` and put it anywhere you want the files listed. Be sure to set the prefix for the URL path and the pattern for the file type which you want listed. If you list all files then you'll need to remove `.` and remove\handle `..` directories for Linux servers (in Windows, PHP will do this for you).

Comment: Is there any online tool like URL Fuzzer for us noobs?

Comment: If you just want to use a list of files which you already know then use the code above and replace `$files=glob("*.txt");` with `$files=array("add.txt","your.jpg","files.png","here.pdf");`. You could also fill that array from a file which is just a listing of file names.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php IOW, `$files=file("file.list");`

Comment: To save the files look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url